# Is there a nice way to make a Kendo custom widget, using Typescript classes?

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, typescript

The documentation for creating custom Kendo widgets is good enough, and leads to something like:

```
declare var kendo: kendo;

// To be able to get types, we can express the widget as this interface
interface ICustomDatePicker {    
    options: () => kendo.ui.DatePickerOptions;
}

; (function ($:JQueryStatic, window:any, document:Document, undefined?) {
    var CustomDatePicker: ICustomDatePicker = (<any>kendo.ui.DatePicker).extend({
        init: function (element, options:kendo.ui.DatePickerOptions) {
            var self = this;            
            // base call to initialize widget
            (<any>kendo.ui.DatePicker).fn.init.call(self, element, options);
        },
        options: {
            // the name is what it will appear as off the kendo namespace (i.e. kendo.ui.CustomDatePicker). 
            // The jQuery plugin would be jQuery.fn.kendoCustomDatePicker.
            name: "CustomDatePicker"
        }
    });
    // This makes it work as a jQuery plugin
    (<any>kendo.ui).plugin(CustomDatePicker);
})(jQuery, window, document);
```

A typescript file with that above, let's me do things like: `$("#datePicker").kendoCustomDatePicker({});` and it all works beautifully.

My question is, is there a better way to write this in class form? My original thought is this:

```
module Foo {
    class CustomDatePicker extends kendo.ui.DatePicker {
        constructor(element, options) {
            super(element, options);
        }
    }
    (<any>kendo.ui).plugin(CustomDatePicker);
}
```

But that doesn't work (when calling the same `$("#datePicker").kendoCustomDatePicker({});`. [This Gist](https://gist.github.com/joeriks/4754169) gets closer, but I think the syntax is a bit funky - that the class doesn't extend the control directly. Any ideas?

### Update 1

Looking at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17094473/276461), I'm trying to find a way to clean up setting the options by having it IN the class. I've gotten the following to semi-work, though it breaks down for some options and not others:

```
constructor(element: Element, options?: kendo.ui.TimePickerOptions) {
    super(element, options);
    $.extend(this.options, <kendo.ui.TimePickerOptions>{
        format: "hh:mm tt",
        parseFormats: ["HH:mm", "hh:mm tt"]
    });
}
```

In this case, it respects that format and you can see it working. If you try and do the following:

```
$.extend(this.options, <kendo.ui.TimePickerOptions>{
    format: "hh:mm tt",
    parseFormats: ["HH:mm", "hh:mm tt"]
});
```

.. it doesn't work, doesn't parse the input at all.

Comment: The problem is options must be set before the base constructor is invoked. The TimePicker takes the parseFormats during initialization time only. You can check its source for additional info.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a way but I am not 100% sure it qualifies as "nice". Here is some code which I wrote today and works:

```
class MyTreeView extends kendo.ui.TreeView
{
    constructor(element: Element, options?: kendo.ui.TreeViewOptions) {
        super(element, options);
    }

    static fn;
}

// kendo.ui.plugin relies on the fn.options.name to get the name of the widget
MyTreeView.fn = MyTreeView.prototype;
MyTreeView.fn.options.name = "MyTreeView";

// kendo.ui.plugin which comes with the Kendo TypeScript definitions doesn't include this overload
module kendo.ui {
    export declare function plugin(widget: any, register?: Object, prefix?: String);
}

// register the plugin
kendo.ui.plugin(MyTreeView);

// extend the jQuery interface with the plugin method (needed to be used later)
interface JQuery {
    kendoMyTreeView(options?: kendo.ui.TreeViewOptions): JQuery;
}

// use the plugin
$(function () {
    $("#content").kendoMyTreeView({
        dataSource: [
            {
                text: "Root",
                items: [
                    { text: "Child" }
                ]
            }
        ]
    });
});
```

Comment: Functional, but I see what you mean. The ugly part is defining everything outside of the class.

Comment: Funny, the following works (you can change the format and it'll respect it), but you can't define parseFormats the same way - it just doesn't do anything:

`$.extend(this.options, <kendo.ui.TimePickerOptions>{format: "hh:mm tt"});`

Comment: I've updated the question explaining my comment a little more.